# Click event to dynamically generated toolstripMenuItems from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

I have a little problem with my app.
I just made something like that:
[Tap here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn6zb.png)

And code for this is:

```
        connect.Open();
        SqlCommand testcomm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nazwa from DRUZYNA", connect);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = testcomm;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                drużynyToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Nazwa"].ToString(), null);
            }

        }
        wyświetlToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(drużynyToolStripMenuItem);
```

This list of teams is loaded dynamically from a database. 
My problem is: How to add Click event to selected team from this list?

I would like to ask for tips.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but I guess you'd just add a (click) event handler to your menu and find out there if the item clicked is the one selected in your list.

Comment: [ItemClicked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.itemclicked(v=vs.110).aspx) Should be able to subscribe to that and handle the user selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the form you should subscribe to the toolstrip event [ItemClicked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.itemclicked(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
wyświetlToolStripMenuItem.ItemClicked += MyItemClicked;
```

The event handler:

```
private void MyItemClicked(Object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e) {

      // e contains a field e.ClickedItem.  Use that in here to perform the appropriate action.
     // You will need to cast the Item to the original type and check if it is null.

}
```